# Выделить все слова исключая те, что в теге

Tags: javascript

Например у нас есть строка:

```
let text = 'Lorem ipsum is placeholder text, commonly <span>used in</span> the graphic.'
```

На выходе надо получить строку такого вида:

```
<span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>is</span> <span>placeholder</span> <span>text</span>, <span>commonly</span> <span>used in</span> <span>the</span> <span>graphic</span>.
```

Долго уже мучаюсь с этим вопросом, пока что получилось только выделить все слова исключая знаки.

```
text.replace(/([A-Za-z0-9'<>/]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

Comment: `text.split(/(<span>.+<\/span>)/gm).map( e =>  e.includes('span') ? e : "<span>"+e.split(/\s/).join('</span> <span>')+"</span>" ).join(' ');`

Comment: в целом работает, но в span также попадают знаки, а также перед и после <span>used in</span> добавились пустые <span></span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str = 'Lorem ipsum is placeholder text, commonly <span>used in</span> the graphic.'
// немного измененный и доработанный Ваш вариант:
            // разбиваем по уже существующим эл-там <span> с любым содержимым (включительно)
const tags = str.split(/(<span>.*<\/span>)/g)
    // проходимся по массиву строк
    // если строка содержит span - оставить как есть
    // если не содержит - обернуть слова в span теги
    .map( e => e.includes('span') ? e : e.replace(/([A-Za-z0-9'<>/]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>') )
    // соединяем массив строк, разбитый по эл-там <span>, обратно в строку
    .join('');
    
console.log(tags);
```

Comment: Благодарю! У меня какой-то не такой вопрос был? 2 минуса поставили

Comment: @KolinRo не знаю за что Вам минусы поставили, вопрос обыкновенный, и свои попытки добавили.